# Wicket - getlist() in List printing multiple times

Tags: java, html, list, listview, wicket

**HomePage.java**

```
Table table = new Table("table");
List<String> list = (List<String>) table.getList();
    System.out.println("accessed list:" + list); //returns list from Table.java

    add(new ListView("listview", list) {
        protected void populateItem(ListItem item) {

            item.add(new Label("name", list.get(1)));
            item.add(new Label("type", list.get(3)));
        }
    });
```

Method in **Table.java** -

```
public List<String> getList() {

       return list; 
           }
```

**HomePage.html**

```
<table class="table">
<tr wicket:id="listview">
<td><span wicket:id="name"></span></td>
<td><span wicket:id="type"></span></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

In **HomePage.java** ,

```
  add(new ListView("listview", list) {
  protected void populateItem(ListItem item) {

     item.add(new Label("name", list.get(0))); // printing the value at 1st position multiple times.
     item.add(new Label("type", list.get(1))); // printing the value at 2nd position multiple times.
     }
   });
```

My list consists of 8 String elements, hence its printing **name** and **type** 8 times each.Can Anyone please suggest how to print only once and how to add second row in table(HomePage.html) with same **wicket id:listview**.
I am just a beginner.Any help would be appreciated.Thankyou

**Edit** -

My list consists of - [name,abc,type,largetext,name,bcd,type,number] 
Actually this is a JSON.I have parsed the JSON and created a List to pass this to ListView for display in Table. I have parsed and created a List in Table.java . I have ListView in HomePage.java , so used this code in **HomePage.java** -

```
Table table = new Table("table");
List<String> list = (List<String>) table.getList();
System.out.println("accessed list:" + list); //returns list from Table.java
```

Trying this list value to pass to ListView in **HomePage.java** for display in Table. But with the code **item.add(new Label("name", list.get(1)));**
 ,its printing multiple times i.e as the size of the list.

Comment: How do you find your string list whether `type` or `name`? I could suggest to have model for `name` , `type` and add to the list . You don't need to say `list.get(0)`,`list.get(1)` which is irrelevant to wicket

Comment: If you want to add a row suggest to have container onclick you add a list and update the `listview`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood, you want to do something like this:

HomePage.java

```
Table table = new Table("table");
    List<String> listOfString = (List<String>) table.getList();

    List<MyPojo> listOfMyPojo = new ArrayList<MyPojo>();
    MyPojo myPojo1 = new MyPojo(listOfString.get(1), listOfString.get(3));
    listOfMyPojo.add(myPojo1);
    MyPojo myPojo2 = new MyPojo(listOfString.get(5), listOfString.get(7));
    listOfMyPojo.add(myPojo2);

    add(new ListView<MyPojo>("listview", listOfMyPojo) {
        protected void populateItem(ListItem<MyPojo> item) {
            MyPojo myPojo = item.getModelObject();
            item.add(new Label("name", myPojo.getName()));
            item.add(new Label("type", myPojo.getType()));
        }
    });
```

Comment: I am using MyPojo as this - PersonList mypojo1 = new PersonList(listOfString.get(0), listOfString.get(1));
  listOfBean.add(mypojo1);

  PersonList mypojo2 = new PersonList(listOfString.get(2), listOfString.get(3));
  listOfBean.add(mypojo2);

  PersonList mypojo3 = new PersonList(listOfString.get(4), listOfString.get(5));
  listOfBean.add(mypojo3);
  
This is working but for many values,its problematic creating so many instances.Can you please suggest if I can use iteration...instead of creating an instance so many times? So that the values gets added dynamically.Thankyou in advance

Answer (score 1):

I did not understand what you want to do exactly but I think that the best way to do that is to create a POJO holding the name and type attributes:

```
public class MyPojo {
private String name;
private String type;
public MyPojo(String name, String type) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getType() {
    return type;
}
public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}   

}
```

And then create a simple Listview using that POJO as a model object:

HTML code:

```
<table class="table">
<tr wicket:id="listview">
<td><span wicket:id="name"></span></td>
<td><span wicket:id="type"></span></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

JAVA code:

```
List<MyPojo> list = new ArrayList<MyPojo>();
//fill your list with the values you want to display
    for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
        MyPojo myPojo = new MyPojo("name" + i, "type" + i);
        list.add(myPojo);
    }
//and then use a ListView component
    add(new ListView<MyPojo>("listview", list) {
        protected void populateItem(ListItem<MyPojo> item) {
            MyPojo myPojo = item.getModelObject();
            item.add(new Label("name", myPojo.getName()));
            item.add(new Label("type", myPojo.getType()));
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thankyou so much.... I have edited the question and added more info.Please refer once.I have a doubt that by creating MyPojo , we are using values from MyPojo to ListView. But my **List** is in **Table.java** , where shall we access that **LIST** in HomePage.java or MyPojo.java?

Comment: You have to access the table List in HomePage.java and create a new MyPojo instance foreach pair (name,type) then add that instance to the list of MyPojo

Comment: I have created MyPojo similar to as you suggested but accessed LIST as below - public MyPojo(String name,String name1, String type , String type1) {
     super();
     
     this.name = list.get(0);
     this.type = list.get(1);
     this.name1 = list.get(2); 
     this.type1 = list.get(3); 
     
 } and accessed these values in HomePage.java but I am able to access each value individually.How to access 2 or more name values in one attribute by using loop?Can you please explain in detail programmatically? Thankyou in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to name your classes and objects in an appropriate way to make your code more readable. You can proceed like this :

```
List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfString.size() - 1; i += 2) {
        Person person = new Person(listOfString.get(i), listOfString.get(i + 1));
        persons.add(person);
    }
```